# Filter/sort image collection according to one of its band values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to filter/sort two sub image collections out of one image collection. The sub collections would be filtered/selected by higher 20% and lower 20% of one of its band values.

In other words, what I try to do is:

1. load image collection;
2. calculate and add NDWI index to this collection;
3. use that new ndwi index band to select/sort/filter two new image
   collections.

One would consist of images with the lower 20% NDWI index values; and the other would consist of images with the higher 20% of NDWI index values.

So far I tried to use the `arraySlice`. It works, but unfortunately I only managed to calculate an image, which consists of the mean of the images with the lower/higher 20% ndwi index.

My next step would be to calculate, for either of these two new image collections, several other indices and apply a combined reducer. Therefore I need an image collection, and not just a composite.

Basically, I am just trying to use the ndwi index values as a filter for my image collection.

Please find a toy script here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8101949c01e192cc8caba4dccff25583

Comment: I think there is not such a way to do this for large areas, as you will have a different amount of observations at pixels across your study area. See here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/988455990f0185c9fc528b0eb9ccffda. A workaround would be unmask() all values as zeros, but then getting the percentile range is distorted. Best is possibly keeping the image collection in the array and do your calculations depending on the number of observations at every pixel.